# Cut last 500 lines from logfile

Tags: command-line-interface

I want to cut the last 500 lines from a logfile and save it to a new file. Is there any unix command for this?

Answer (score 7):

```
tail -n 500 logfile >newfile
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Doesn't actually remove the lines from the original file, but I'm sure he didn't want to do that anyway.